# Help with adjusting line-spacing on custom title page

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I'm making a custom title page for my PhD proposal, following the [Title Creation article of LaTeX in Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation). However, after many tries I just can't get the title to have a bigger line-spacing. I was wondering if anyone can help me with this issue.

Heres the image of the issue and a sample document:
[image: title]

Sample Document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

    % Upper part of the page
    %\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo}\\[1cm]    
    \textsc{\large Department}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large University}\\[3.5cm]

    \textsc{\Large Proposal bla bla}\\[1.5cm]

    % Title
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    {\Huge \bfseries Proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title}\\[0.4cm]
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    % Author and supervisor
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Autor:}\\
        John Smith
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Orientador:} \\
        Dr.~Albert \textsc{Einstein}
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

    \vfill

    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today}

    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are changing the font size to `\Huge` inside a group, but the group ends before the paragraph, so the line spacing for `\Huge` has no effect; to correct this, you must end the paragraph (using `\par`, for example) before closing the group:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

    % Upper part of the page
    %\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo}\\[1cm]    
    \textsc{\large Department}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large University}\\[3.5cm]

    \textsc{\Large Proposal bla bla}\\[1.5cm]

    % Title
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    {\Huge \bfseries Proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title\par}

\vspace{0.4cm}
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    % Author and supervisor
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Autor:}\\
        John Smith
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Orientador:} \\
        Dr.~Albert \textsc{Einstein}
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

    \vfill

    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today}

    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

If you want to increase even more the line spacing, you can change `\linespread` for the title; a little example using `\linespread{1.5}` (notice again the `\par` command necessary for the change to have effect):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

    % Upper part of the page
    %\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logo}\\[1cm]    
    \textsc{\large Department}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large University}\\[3.5cm]

    \textsc{\Large Proposal bla bla}\\[1.5cm]

    % Title
\linespread{1.5}
    \HRule\\
    {\Huge\bfseries Proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title proposal title\par}

\vspace*{0.4cm}
    \HRule\\[1.5cm]

\linespread{1}
    % Author and supervisor
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{Autor:}\\
        John Smith
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{Orientador:} \\
        Dr.~Albert \textsc{Einstein}
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

    \vfill

    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today}

    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The main fix is the addition of `\par`, you should mention it.

Comment: `\par` isn't only necessary to enable the effects of `\linespread{1.5}`, but also to enable the default line spacing of `\Huge`.

Comment: @lockstep yes; I was editing the answer to add this. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcosRoriz You're welcome. By the way, I updated my answer with new information that could be useful.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The accept vote to this answer brought you in the very exclusive 100k rep club! Congratulations!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks very much. The new info helped me a lot too! =)